# How to wire up ability to click through main spreadsheet cell to source spreadsheet cell, and make main readonly?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this configuration:

```
=QUERY({
  IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<id>/edit", "custom!A:D");
  IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<id>/edit", "hebrew!A:D");
  IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<id>/edit", "sanskrit!A:D");
  IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<id>/edit", "swahili!A:D")
}, "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col1 is not Null")
```

And my sheet looks like this:

[image]

I placed that `QUERY` in the upper left cell on the `main` sheet.

I would now like to do 2 things:

1. When I click (or perhaps double click) a cell in the `main` sheet, it should navigate to the appropriate cell in the source sheet and focus it ready to edit.
2. I would like the `main` sheet to be readonly, so it can't be edited.

How can I accomplish that? That way I can look for validation errors in the main sheet (using `=COUNTIF($A:$A,"="&A1) < 2`), and I can click in to edit and it takes me to the appropriate sheet place so I can fix the error.

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?